# Definition of profinite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, topological-groups, profinite-groups

Consider the following definition:

> A **profinite group** is a topological group that is compact, Hausdorff, and admits a neighborhood basis of $1$ made of normal subgroups.

My question is: it is restrictive to replace *neighborhood basis* with *open neighborhood basis*?

In other words, I am trying to see if given a neighborhood basis of $1$ made of normal subgroups is it possible to construct a neighborhood basis of $1$ made of OPEN normal subgroups.

For a generic topological space this is trivial, because given $U_x$ a neighborhood in a neighborhood basis of a point $x$, then by definition there exists an open set $A$ such that $x\in A\subseteq U_x$, and so we can replace $U_x$ with $A$ to obtain an open neighborhood basis. The problem here is that this method doesn't necessarily preserve the normal subgroup structure.

Comment: I believe your definition assumes that a neighbourhood is open. Otherwise, what does it mean to be a neighbourhood basis?

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim In general a neighborhood basis of $x$ is a family $\{V_i\}_{i \in I}$ of neighborhoods of $x$ such that, if $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$, then exists $V_i \subseteq U$. The problem is that neighborhood are not necessarily open, but only sets that contain an open set that contains the point.

Comment: Ah okay, that's fair. An equivalent definition is topological groups that are compact Hausdorff and totally disconnected. Perhaps you can utilize this?

Comment: But it is not hard to realise that every subgroup of a topological group containing an open set is necessarily open. So it's still not clear what your question is.

Comment: @kabenyuk I didn't know that fact, but this clearly answers the question. Thanks